# Problema con los acentos al escribir el contenido de un txt en html con ajax

Tags: jquery

En html tengo puesto meta charset="utf-8" y el texto es un txt plano. Tengo esta funcion, con jquery para mostrar lo que hay en un txt en un div.

```
$(document).ready(function () {  

        $("#inicio").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url : "prueba.txt",
               dataType: "text",
               success : function (data) {
                       $(".mostrarAqui").html(data);
               }
             });
        })
```

He leido que una solucion es leer el documento en php que ya tiene funciones para leerlo y luego mostrarlo con un echo, ¿pero hay alguna forma de no tener que pasar por php?

Comment: saludos prueba colocando " <meta charset="ISO-8859-1"/>"..en lugar de "utf-8"

Comment: No funciono poner ISO-8859-1.

Answer (score 0):

Me contexto a mi mismo con una solucion que he encontrado. Al guardar el documento de texto, guardar como, codificacion utf-8 y ya esta.